# Is there any scalar that can mirror a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am visualizing what scaling a vector does to its original vector, it can expand it, shrink it, flip it the other way, but is there such thing as a scalar changing the only the $y$ value of a vector?

For instance you have the vector $(2,3)$ does there exist such scalar that would produce $(2,-3)$?

I am just curious. I think there isn't one, but just wanted to check with you guys.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! The word *scalar* already describes what can be achieved quite well: you can scale the vector, but the direction stays fixed. So no, you can't change just one coordinate by scaling, when both are non-zero.

Comment: There exists no such scalar.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that there is a scalar $s$ such that $s(2,3)=(2,-3)$. Then we have $2s=2$ and $3s=-3$, which gives $s=1$ and $s=-1.$ Conclusion ?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. If $(2,-3)=\alpha(2,3)$ for some scalar $\alpha$, then equating the first components gives $2\alpha = 2$, and equating second components gives $3\alpha = -3$. Clearly no value of $\alpha$ satisfies both these equations.